# How to add more variables according to condition in ArgumentException

Tags: c#

I have one shipping Id in my hand, my purpose is that I check database whether this shipping Id has already assigned to Plan Id or not. If Shipping Id has already assigned, I throw Argument Exception `{Shipping Id} has already assigned to Existing {Plan Id}`.

I can do this for one Plan Id. But if this shipping Id has already assigned more than one Plan Id , I should throw all of this Plan Id. But I can't do using Argument Exception .

My Code:

```
foreach (var existingPlanId in checkExistingDateWithOtherPlanIds){
    var checkPlanId = existingPlanId.ShippingSerieses.Contains(existingShippingId);
    if (checkPlanId)
    {
      throw new ArgumentException($"ERROR#3% Shipping Id has already assigned to Plan Id: {Environment.NewLine}" +
                                  $"ShippingID -> Plan ID {Environment.NewLine}" +
                                  $"{existingShippingId.ShippingId} -> {existingPlanId.PlanId}, {positioningPlanToChange.PlanId}");                      
    }

}
```

Expected Result:

`Shipping Id has already assigned to Plan Id:`

`ShippingID -> Plan ID`

`423 -> 601, 263, 321 341 , 543`

Comment: Why can't you? The message you're writing is a string, which you can fill with anything you like...

Comment: First, i guess you misuse ArgumentException for a kind of error/exception ArgumentException is not commonly used for (instead, i would suggest you create and throw your own exception type). But i could be wrong about that, since your code sample does not reveal enough context to be 100% sure. Secondly (and more related to your actual problem), in the loop just collect all conflicting/violating IDs (or, if possible, use some Linq construct instead). Then _after_ the loop, if conflicting/violating/invalid IDs have been collected, throw your exception with those collected IDs...

Comment: Suppose I collect all Ids in list. In loop how can throw each element ?

Comment: You can only throw once, thus throw one exception with all the violating IDs...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your case looks like you need your own `Exception` successor:

```cs
public class PlanException : Exception
{
    public int PlanId { get; }

    public int ShippingId { get; }

    public PlanException(string message, int planId, int shippingId)
      : base(message)
    {
        PlanId = planId;
        ShippingId = shippingId;
    }
}
```

Or, you can use the [`Data`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.exception.data?view=netframework-4.7.2) property of the `Exception` class.

```
public static class ExceptionExtensions
{
    public static Exception AddData(this Exception exception, object key, object value)
    {
        exception.Add(key, value);

        return exception;
    }
}

. . .

throw new ArgumentException("Shipping id is already assigned.").AddData("planId", planId)
                                                               .AddData("shippingId", shippingId);
```

`ArgumentException` is not so suitable exception for your case. Usually you can throw `ArgumentException` when an argument has unexpected value that you can check without a complex code.

For example: "an argument should be positive", "an argument should be between 2 and 10", and so on.

Your case is more complex as I can see, so maybe the `InvalidOperationException` is the more suitable exception for you.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you want the program to stop after your throw the exception or if you want it to continu executing. 
From your code snippet, Your program will stop after the first throw.

If you want it to continu executing add a try catch block as bellow

```
foreach (var existingPlanId in checkExistingDateWithOtherPlanIds){
    var checkPlanId = existingPlanId.ShippingSerieses.Contains(existingShippingId);
    if (checkPlanId)
    {
        try {
            throw new ArgumentException($"ERROR#3% Shipping Id has already assigned to Plan Id: {Environment.NewLine}" +
                                      $"ShippingID -> Plan ID {Environment.NewLine}" +
                                      $"{existingShippingId.ShippingId} -> {existingPlanId.PlanId}, {positioningPlanToChange.PlanId}");  
        }   
        catch {}
    }
}
```

If you are planing to stop the program execution after the exception is thrown but still show all the related Products. You have to throw the exception at the end of the loop.